# Capture modifier keys pressing ( Control, Alt, Shift o CMD )

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard

I know how to detect key pressing. All keys except Control, Alt, Shift and CMD.

How can i detect when this keys are being pressed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to detect these keys in something like a `NSView` object, have a look at the `NSResponder` class. When you overwrite a `NSView` class (or one of its sublcasses), you can overwrite `keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent`[(Apple Documentation)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSResponder). When you call `[theEvent modifierFlags]`, a `NSUInteger` bitfield is returned, which you can then evaluate.

For instance, with

```
if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask) {
   ...
}
```

you can check if the Command key is pressed.

See Apple's [Cocoa Event-handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i), especially the section "Handling Key Events" for more information.

Comment: That does NOT catch modifier keys when they are pressed. That will only let you know what modifier key was pressed when a normal key is pressed.

Answer (score 4):

in

```
- (void) flagsChanged: (NSEvent *)theEvent
```

`[theEvent keyCode]` gives a number for `CRTL`, `SHIFT`, `ALT`, etc, so you only need to toggle a variable for those modifiers, set to `0` at start.

if you use OpenGL you may need to set:

```
-(BOOL) canBecomeKeyWindow
```

Comment: Please use code markdown (\`code\`), new lines and be a little clearer.